# Regex for Alphanumeric, delete, backspace,space, But not special charcters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I using regex to allow alpha numeric in textbox but don't know how to allow backspace and delete also. Now user not able to delete ,space, backspace.

Here is the code

```
   $('#MemberBasicInfor_FirstName, #MemberBasicInfor_LastName').on('keypress', function (event) {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
        var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
        if (!regex.test(key)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

please modify and allow to delete, space and backspace.

Comment: RegEx tests strings, lists of _characters_. The delete key press cannot be stored as a character. Instead, you should use [`event.keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode), or something of the likes. If anyone has another solution that is not deprecated, please share.

Answer (score 1):

This is highly dependent on which browser you're using, Chrome and Edge won't even fire `keypress` for Delete and Backspace. For Firefox `keypress` is fired a lot more generally, even things like the arrow keys will trigger it.

Backspace has character code 8 and can be represented using `\b`. Space is just a space. Delete, the arrow keys, Home and End will all give character code 0. Firefox doesn't take Ctrl or Alt into consideration so something like `Ctrl+v` would be treated as simply `v`, you'd need to adapt your code to check modifier keys if that's a concern. Likewise most browser allow copy and paste via other techniques that don't involve a keypress at all, so none of those will be affected.

All that said, I believe the RegExp you'd need is something like this:

```
var regex = /[a-zA-Z0-9\b\0 ]/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Backspace isn't RegExable, so you might better using ASCII codes.

```
$('#MemberBasicInfor_FirstName, #MemberBasicInfor_LastName').on('keypress', function (event) {
    var allowedCodes = [[8, 8], [32, 32], [48, 57], [65, 90], [97, 122], [127, 127]];
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    if (!allowedCodes(codePair => key.charCodeAt(0) <= codePair[0] || key.charCodeAt(0) >= codePair[1])) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Backspace can be matched in a RegExp using `\b` inside a character class, it's equivalent to character code 8.